# Apply animation length change

Tags: animation

I have changed the animation length of a clip (as in the picture below), by changing the start and end time..

When I export the model and use it somewhere, it still seems to be using the original animation length.

Do I need to 'apply' the animation length change somehow (like with applying 'Scale') in order to get it working?

Thanks

[image]

---

Update based on comments:

I am seeing this (where 50-77 is the frame length I want for the object, not just the scene):

[image]

Comment: If you are exporting images (jpg, png) instead of a movie, make sure that you've removed the images that go beyond the new length, otherwise they will still be in the folder, maybe it's your probelm here?

Comment: not sure how to check that, when I click on an animation or image option in the selector on the right, I can't see anything which would suggest images going beyond the length

Comment: did you choose images or video? If you chose images, go into the folder and remove the additional images

Comment: I'm not sure where you mean, in my 'Outliner', I see 'Scene Collection' with 'fire_part_00' 'fire_part__01' etc (the example is an animated campfire). Under each 'fire_part', there is an 'Animation' and 'Mesh'. I have updated the question with a photo.

Comment: do you render your animation as a video or as a series of images? please show the Output panel, or share your file

Comment: I've been exporting it as a gltf for importing into a React site

Answer (score 0):

The adjustments you are making are the frame range for the scene, not the object itself. The moment you import the object into a new scene, it will use the new scene Frame Range settings in the Output Properties box.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to do that, do you mean just exporting it (e.g. as gltf) and then reimporting it into a 'new' scene? (this didn't seem to work for me)